# How to set up time capsule as repeater

Tags: networking, wifi, router

I have a modem router and a timecapsule. I would like to connect 'wirelessly' my timecapsule to the router and use it to connect other devices to it with wired connections. Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After [further research](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19434160#19434160) using the timecapsule as repeater seems like a non-option with a non-Apple router. Furthermore according to [apple support](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2392292?start=0&tstart=0) it seemed like  bad idea to start with.